# How to offset currentNanoTime

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a game loop that looks like this

```
new AnimationTimer() {
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
                if (isPaused == false) {
                    double t = (currentNanoTime - startNanoTime) / 1000000000.0;
                    timerCorner = Math.round(t * 100.0) / 100.0;
                } else {
                    ...
                }
}
```

I would like to pause my timer without stopping the AnimationTimer loop. I thought it simplest to just accumulate an offset during the else statement, but you can't overwrite variables within the AnimationTimer loop. I think I can overcome this by updating a value within a class object, but don't know how to do so accurately? Or is there a better method.

My game is a time challenge so it's important the clock stops when the pause menu is active. The pause looks like this

```
    else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                                // System.out.println("Escape key is pressed");
                                isPaused = true;
                                ...
    }
```

Basically, I want to calculate a value X such that

```
double t = currentNanoTime - startNanoTime - X
```

counts up from when the game was paused, rather then jumping ahead to where CurrentNanoTime is now.

Comment: Side note: always prefer `!isPaused` to `isPaused == false`. The latter is easily confused with `isPaused = false`, which can cause very unexpected results.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. What does 'don't know how to do so accurately' mean?

Comment: I've tried adding 0.15 each Animation timer tick to an object to act as an offset but obviously that's not accurate, that's just sort of close. I want to calculate a number that when subtracted to currentNanoTime, it will continue counting from when the pause was initially pressed.

I have edited my question to be clearer sorry!

Comment: It's still a little vague because your actual problem is unobvious and neither is what you tried, which you should include. Take a look at [ask] and try to write something closer to a [MCVE]. If you can, using precise terminology is also helpful - what is 'update a value in a class object'? Do you mean an instance variable? What is the nature of the inaccuracy? Etc.

Comment: You're right, i've cluttered my question with excess information.
In a JavaFX AnimationTimer loop, how do I count currentNanoTime from a different starting point in a separate variable?